# black screen after disabling wayland

Tags: xorg, wayland

I'm on ubuntu 22.04.1 and i need to switch to Xorg to use a remote display application. I disabled wayland from the /etc/gdm/custom.conf file in hopes it would work with X because this version of Ubuntu is apparently supposed to ship with it installed, but now after I boot, all I can see is a black screen.

Anything I could do to enable wayland again or better, make it work with X?

Only answer I found on Google suggested booting into recovery mode and repairing broken packages but that didn’t work.

Comment: If you can log in in recovery mode, can you undo the changes you did to `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`? Would that help?

Comment: @Levente This worked, thanks!

Comment: O.k. now you can try something: on the normal login screen, at least on version 20.04, there is a cogwheel icon in the bottom corner. If one clicks that, it offers a choice for the alternative display server. So, it could maybe look something like "Ubuntu on X.org" or something similar. This is how I imagine, based on how I saw it on 20.04. You would need to log out with your user, and then study the login screen to spot this cogwheel...

Comment: @Levente yup i tried this first but it did the same thing and turned my screen black.